# how to create custom keyboard extension in react native for IOS and Android?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

How to create a custom keyboard extension in react native for IOS and Android?
e.g. Gboard, Microsoft Swiftkey keyboard

```
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.71.8",
```